# run 'service php5-fpm restart' without using sudo

Tags: shell, sudo, password, services

I am integrating my cakephp projects using jenkins.

Right now, I am exploring the use of Phing. There is one task where I need to run

```
service php5-fpm restart
```

So far I tried to do this manually. I cannot do so unless i do it with `sudo`

Please advise how I can execute this command without using sudo at all?

I know there is an option where I can simply put the user that Phing is using inside sudoers and then not prompt for password, but for security reasons, that is not ideal. So I prefer to ask how to do this without getting prompted for password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last paragraph of your question is misleading, at least for me. If your goal is to find a way to invoke `service` as user `Phing` without getting asked for a passphrase I would do it with `sudo`. I will try to answer you question as I understand it, since I don't grasp what speak against the use of `sudo` in your case.

---

Just add the line

```
Defaults        exempt_group=Phing
```

to `/etc/sudoers`. This line adds the user `Phing` to a group on which `sudo` doesn't lay down path and password requirements.

Further you have to add the line

```
Phing ALL=(root) /full/path/to/service
```

or alter an existing line of `Phing`, so that `sudo` grants him access to `service`.

After that

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

shouldn't ask `Phing` for a passphrase any longer.

If you want it a bit more strict you can instead add the line

```
Phing ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/service
```

without using `exempt_group`. Then you have to give `sudo` the full path of `service` (if it's not located in the standard paths), so command spoofing isn't possible.

If you want to save some typing, you can also alias `sudo service` or `sudo /full/path/to/service` in your shell with `service`.

Comment: The reason for my last paragraph is because i got an answer at security stackexchange here http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26101/restarting-nginx-with-jenkins-or-phing-is-it-safe-to-allow-jenkins-to-run-sudo/26113

Comment: I am not able to find the full path to service. Googled like mad. Can advise?

Comment: i used `which service` and it gave me /usr/sbin/service. By the way, the exempt method did not work. the Phing ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/service worked!

Comment: Please note that this solution practically gives the "Phing" user to every service that is running. In most cases, this wouldn't be considered an optimal solution.